# Reopen question - logic changed?

Tags: support

There are suddenly a lot of re-open requests (currently 114), and upon inspection most have minor editing.
Most of these edits are not not by people who posted the original question.

Is the system flagging any changes to closed post as a re-open request ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Previously, only edits to a closed question within the first five days pushed it back to the *Reopen* queue. That was the time frame after which *on hold* would change to *closed*.

The [rules have changed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078):

> Currently, this means that a closed question will automatically be
>   added to the reopen queue when it is...
>
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by the author. Or,
> - ...Edited (body edits only) within 5 days of closure by a 3rd-party, provided the editor has not also flagged the question or voted to
>     delete it. Or,
> - ...Sufficiently popular, where popularity is calculated based on question score, top answer score, or views per month. We're still
>     tweaking the exact thresholds for these, but right now they're fairly
>     generous - however, the most popular closed questions are being added
>     to the queue first.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078

Comment: Thanks for the link. Apparently it's more complex than I thought.